# What does "readily available" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Vehicles transporting dangerous materials should have an inventory of
>   the materials being transported **readily available**.

What does "readily available" refer to in this sentence? Does it refer to "readily available inventory"?

Comment: Yes. *An inventory of the materials being transported **should be** readily available* (on/with the vehicles)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same sense of *readily* as *readily available inventory*, but it isn't quite the same. *Readily available inventory* is the mass noun sense of *inventory*, meaning those items that are available to sell, dispense, etc. without any particular delay (e.g. the inventory that is in a local store, rather than needing ordering from a regional warehouse). In this case, *inventory* is in its singular sense, a list of items that are kept somewhere or carried in something.

This is saying that a vehicle transporting dangerous materials should have a list of what it is transporting, and be able to produce it on demand, quickly, should anyone ask for it.